# Read from a Stream, modify strings and write to file

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems

I have a console app the reports on files that have been updated since the last time the app ran and outputs the files full path to a text file. I need to modify these file names in the text file to run AECOsim's (drafting package) native batch processing tool.

I need to turn the text file of strings

```
F:\IOP\EW\02_Plant\99_CAD\autodesk\navisworks\01_Models\ST\0-EW-2110-ST-003.dgn
F:\IOP\EW\02_Plant\99_CAD\autodesk\navisworks\01_Models\ST\0-EW-2120-ST-001.dgn
F:\IOP\EW\02_Plant\99_CAD\autodesk\navisworks\01_Models\ST\0-EW-2120-ST-002.dgn
```

To output like this. The first 5 lines need to be there so I would assume that I write the modified strings to an existing file starting from the 6th line down.

```
[SETTINGS=bpOptions]
   logFile=_USTN_OUT:batchprocess.log
   cmdFileName=F:\IOP\EW\Standards\data\Batchprocess\751EW-ST-IFC.txt
   clearLog=1
   initialModel=-18
[SOURCE=F:\IOP\EW\01_Models\ST\0-EW-2110-ST-003.dgn]
[MODEL=Design Model]
[SOURCE=F:\IOP\EW\01_Models\ST\0-EW-2120-ST-001.dgn]
[MODEL=Design Model]
[SOURCE=F:\IOP\EW\01_Models\ST\0-EW-2120-ST-002.dgn]
[MODEL=Design Model]
```

Any advice on which api's to use would be muchly appreciated

Comment: Well then, you have **some stuff to learn**, **1)** How to break apart a *FileName* **2)** How to write to (what looks like) an old fashioned *Ini File* **3)** **how to ask a question** and **the etiquette of *StackOverflow*** , see [ask] and [tour] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty of this would be to iterate over the lines or a collection lines for each and do a string replacement to replace or remove the text you don't need

Something like

```
var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
...

foreach( var file in fileLines ) {

    sb.AppendLine($"[SOURCE={file.Replace("","")}]");
    sb.AppendLine($"[MODEL=Design Model]");
}

return sb.ToString();
```

That said, if you may need a regex replacement if you need something more dynamic